# Base64 encoded image not sending properly in http post body on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest

I have slight issue in my iOS app. I'm getting a picture from user and then encoding it into base64 and sending that to the server. Somehow the server isn't receiving proper base64 string (It removes all the + signs).

Below is the Http request service

```
 let baseUrl = "my_endpoint"

func request(endpoint: String,
             parameters: [String: Any],
             completion: @escaping (Result<finalMessage, Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl+endpoint) else {
        completion(.failure(NetworkingError1.badUrl))
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var components = URLComponents()
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

    for (key, value) in parameters {

        let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
        queryItems.append(queryItem)
    }

    components.queryItems = queryItems

    let credentialData = "xxxxx".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let queryItemData = components.query?.data(using: .utf8)

    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64Credentials)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("xxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "API-KEY")
    //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod="POST"
    request.httpBody = queryItemData

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {}
```

How I'm passing the parameters code (respectively)

```
    let parameters = ["insuredName": name!, "insuredCellNo": number!,
                      "insuredEmail": email!, "insuredAddress": address!,
                      "insuredCity": city!, "insuredCnic": cnic!,
                      "policyDate": policyDate!, "filerStatus": filerStatus!,
                      "insuredBy": insuredBy!, "vehicleMake": vehicleMake!,
                      "vehicleSubMake": vehicleSubmake!, "vehicleRegNo": vehicleRegNo!,
                      "vehicleType": vehicleType!, "capacity": capacity!, "vehicleModel": vehicleModel!, "vehicleEngineNo": vehicleEno!,
                      "vehicleChassisNo": vehicleChNo!,
                       "vehicleCategory": vehicleCat!,
                       "trackerStatus": trackerStatus!, "vehicleValue": vehicleValue!, "rate": preferences.string(forKey: "rate")!,
                      "imageMotorFront": self.image1!,
                      "imageMotorBack": self.image2!,
                      "imageMotorRight": self.image3!, "imageMotorLeft": self.image4!]



    xyz.request(endpoint: "/xzzz", parameters: parameters) {[weak self] (result)
```

How I'm converting imageview image to base 64:

```
        let imageData = image!.pngData()
        let imageStr = imageData?.base64EncodedString()
        self.image4 = imageStr
```

Comment: What exactly is your payload supposed to be here as a whole. I am pretty sure you are having issues with using `URLComponents`. And then `String(describing: value)` is probably not helping either. Anyway, what I assume is that your query items will encode your base64 string to percent encoded for some characters like a plus sign.

Comment: My payload is a [string:string]. With all the parameters as strings except one which is a base64 encoded string

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not the case from your code. The payload is what you put into body which in your case is `queryItemData`. And this is created with `components.query?.data(using: .utf8)` which is an UTF8 encoded string of data provided by your query. So I assume the output should be like `key1=value1&key2=value2...`. But this is URL encoded which probably encodes some characters to percent encoded which in the end is your issue. Perhaps you are looking for this: `request.httpBody = parameters.map { "\($0.key)=\(String(describing: $0.value))" }.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8)`

Comment: tried this, for some weird reason the base64 being passed to the request removes all the '+' signs in the string.

Comment: How did you find that out? I decoded it back and got the same result with plus symbols using: `print(String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)!)`